# Can't use Maven through a proxy with a Vagrant machine

Tags: maven, ubuntu, proxy, vagrant, jhipster

I'm currently using JHipster on their DevBox (XUbuntu) through a proxy.
I configured everything I could think about in it to use it through a proxy, mainly with the vagrant-proxyconf plugin and by exporting `MAVEN_OPTS` in a shell script inside `/etc/profile.d`.
`npm install` works fine, same for `apt-get` or Firefox.
However, `mvn`, `telnet` or `ping` keep giving me "Connection timed out" errors, with `repo1.maven.org` or `google.com`, even if I give the proxy options as parameters of `mvn` directly.

Comment: If your server is behind a proxy, you may need a specific configuration for Maven. Did you configure Maven proxy in Maven `conf/settings.xml` ?

Comment: Nope, I used `MAVEN_OPTS`, I think it's easier to use in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the problem...

To use Maven through a proxy you can set the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable like this: `-Dhttp.proxyHost=<domain> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<domain> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port>` for a proxy URL like this: `<protocol>://<domain>:<port>`.

I simply used `<protocol>://<domain>` instead of `<domain>`...

But `ping` and `telnet` still won't work, even if the `HTTP(S)_PROXY` environment variables, lower and uppercase, are set. Well, I don't really need them so it's just strange but not harmful.